# Paypal Sandbox integration

Tags: paypal

I am using simple form submit to paypal sandbox url 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/au/cgi-bin/webscr'.

```
<input type="hidden" name="amount" value=11>
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
  <input type="hidden" name="no_shipping" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value='biz@ee.com'>
  <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="audio">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value=USD>
  <input type="hidden" name="UseSandbox" value="true">
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value=returnURL/">
  <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value=cancel_url/">
  <input type="image" align='centre' src="http://www.paypal.com/en_AU/i/btn/x-click-but01.gif" name="submit" alt="Make payments with PayPal - it's fast, free and secure!">
```

If I am already logged into my sandbox account, everything works fine ,I am redirected to payment page with my merchants test store showing the amount and right side showing payment alternatives. But if i logout from sandbox  and then make a payment through the payment page it redirects to login to sandbox paypal..When the buyer buys the item why would he require to login to sandbox. Why cant get direct access to sellers test store.

Answer (score 4):

You must be logged in to https://developer.paypal.com/ to access any pages on the *.sandbox.paypal.com domain. That's simply how Sandbox works.
As the Sandbox is for testing and development purposes, no real buyer would ever see this, since you obviously wouldn't send them to the Sandbox page.

Comment: Thanks,That means this would not happen when I use my real paypal account.In real scenario the buyer would be redirected to merchants payment page without any login requirements.